# Cannot inflate option menu with toolbar in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-toolbar, optionmenu

In this app I have MainFragment, I tried to add action bar and toolbar with option menu to it, the action bar is shown but the option menu isn't, also the back button not working even though I add the code to call `onBackPressed`

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.mml.mig33.fragments.MainFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Mig33.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Mig33.PopupOverlay">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_32sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_32sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
                android:tint="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userNameTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:text="username"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_18ssp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainFragment class**

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main) {

    private var _binding: FragmentMainBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        binding.toolbar.apply {
            title = ""
            setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_back_24)
            setNavigationOnClickListener {

                activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed()

            }

        }

        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val viewPageAdapter = ViewPageAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle)
        binding.viewPager2.adapter = viewPageAdapter
        val tabTitles = arrayOf("Chat", "Search", "Settings")

        TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager2) { tab, position ->
            when (position) {
                0 -> tab.text = tabTitles[0]
                1 -> tab.text = tabTitles[1]
                2 -> tab.text = tabTitles[2]
            }

        }.attach()


    }

    private inner class ViewPageAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
        FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {


        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return 3
        }

        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            return when (position) {
                0 -> ChatFragment()
                1 -> SearchFragment()
                2 -> SettingsFragment()
                else -> ChatFragment()
            }
        }


    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_logout -> {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToLoginFragment()
                findNavController().navigate(action)
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** I used `NoActionBar`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mml.mig33">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Mig33.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Mig33.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

I tested this code in Mainactivity and it's working fine, but I need it on MainFragment

Comment: Menu options is not visible when theme is NoActionBar. Can you check if onCreateOptionsMenu is being called? There is one alternative [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729600/how-to-add-menu-options-when-theme-is-noactionbar-in-style-xml) but have not tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changed `android:theme="@style/Theme.Mig33.NoActionBar` of whole app to theme that support action bar `android:theme="@style/Theme.Mig33"`and keep the activity with no action bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mml.mig33">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Mig33">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Mig33.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the called this in fragment

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `NoActionBar`? You need to use the **theme** that supports **ActionBar**, otherwise your `OnCreateOptionsMenu` will not be called. To add your toolbar, use `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`.

Comment: The meu is in fragment not activity, also I tried this `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)` not working

Comment: Why are you using `noActionBar` ? Apparently your toolbar is not customized. Try removing `noActionBar` please

Answer (score 1):

You should set your toolbar in Main Activity or define the toolbar in every fragments if you want to use NoActionBar theme.

Take a look https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#support_app_bar_variations

Answer (score 0):

You gotta add this in OnCreateView()

```
 Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.new_chat_menu);
```